# Matlab: How to remove brushing marks on a plot

Tags: matlab, function, highlighting, brush

I am using the brushing capability of Matlab in a GUI. I want the brushing marks on plot1 to be removed whenever plot2 is cleared. I looked at [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/marking-up-graphs-with-data-brushing.html) for help, but I didn't find any function/command to remove/eliminate the highlighted brushing marks, except on how to do it manually which it says can be done as:

> Shift+clicking or Shift+dragging highlighted observations eliminates
>   their highlighting and removes them from the selection set

Is there some command/function which can be used to eliminate the highlighted brushed marks?

Answer (score 0):

```
%first get the dataObjects
h = gcf
axesObjs = get(h, 'Children');
dataObjs = get(axesObjs, 'Children'); 
for i=1:length(dataObjs)
    objects=dataObjs{i};
    %for each line object
    for j=1:length(objects)
        t = get(objects(j));
        if  strcmp(t.Type,'line')
            set(objects(j),'BrushData',zeros(1,length(t.BrushData)));
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi. It gives an error at line `if strcmp(t.Type, 'line')` as: `Error using strcmp
Too many input arguments.`

Comment: hmm.. It is likely that t.Type is an array then. What is the output of just `t.Type`?  Also what does it say if you type `which strcmp` ?

Comment: `t = 7x1 struct array`, whereas `t.Type = uimenu`. On entering `which strcmp` in the command window, it says `built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\matlab\strfun\strcmp)`

Comment: Ok - I missed that t could be an array for uimenu items. Try with the updated answer - that should work

Comment: I seem to have missed a for loop. Last try - the answer is updated